# Command to check mount point of usb device

Tags: linux, command-line

From a Linux shell, what command can I use to check if the operating system has assigned a mount point to a USB Memory.

In dmesg we see the kernel messages regarding the hardware and the command lsusb see more features on the device, but not if there is a way to know if the operating system has automatically mounted the device or not.

thanks

Comment: I know cat /etc/mtab but not if there are any additional command. Thanks

Comment: Try *df -h*, the optin only means: use human units (KB, MB,...).

Comment: If the kernel messages told you that, say, `/dev/sdh` was plugged in, then run `mount | grep /dev/sdh` to discover if any partitions on that device have been mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the `lsblk` command.

Eg:

```
lsblk -o name,size,mountpoint
```